# Install zend framework on xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, zend-framework, xampp

I have created virtual host using *hosts* file:

```
127.0.0.1       zend.local
```

*httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/zendtest/public"
    ServerName zend.local
</VirtualHost>
```

I am getting this warnings and error in xampp

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\public\index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library;.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\public\index.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your ZF library is not inside the 2 include paths. It may be inside D:\xampp\php\ . Just look for a folder named Zend. In that case you have to add D:\xampp\php to your include paths which you can do in php.ini file or index.php inside public folder of your project.
In case you cannot find Zend folder, you can always download it and save inside library folder in your project (just outside public).

Side note: I usually ignore Zend folder from my version control if it is in project.

Comment: I have a folder in my xampp in D:\xampp\php\pear\PHP\CodeSniffer\Standards\Zed but don't know it is Zend library or not. I am novice.

Comment: Is it Zed of Zend? You can look for library files inside that folder. In your case there should be Autoloader.php inn Zend. If it exists you can add this path in include_path

Comment: Pardon, It is Zend. It contains one folder named as Sniffs and a file named as ruleset.xml. but there is not autoloader.php file. In my zendtest folder there is a folder named as library but that is empty.

Comment: I have one more library folder in D:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\tests\library

Comment: That one is used only if you are creating test caseslike PHPUnit. You can download Zend library and extract it in library folder in your project. That should work

Comment: Amit, I will appreciate if you can please let me know how to install zend framework on my xampp step by step. I am novice so unable to catch exactly this from other sources.